# Obtain equation solution in a preferred form

Tags: equation-solving

How can the solution of the following equation be obtained in a specified, preferred form?

```
Reduce[3^(c - 1) == 7/E, c, Reals]
```

The result obtained is:

```
c == (-1 + Log[3] + Log[7])/Log[3]
```

However, one can see that the final result could also be written as follows:

```
Log[3, 7/E] + 1
```

How can I obtain the latter result, either from `Reduce`, or through further manipulation?

Comment: The first thing you have to do is set `SetSystemOptions[
 "SimplificationOptions" -> {"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False}]`. The next is figure how to combine the logs....